How can I randomly replace the values remaining at least one value using python?
I tried to replace the some of major values in the tensor with the unique value while maintaining at least one value.
For example, given edge_index, I want to change it as below.
edge_index = torch.as_tensor([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8],
                              [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 7]])

result = torch.as_tensor([[5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 7, 8],
                          [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 6]])

In detail, some values appeared more than 2 times in edge_index (i.e., 0, 1, 2, 4, 7).
To avoid unique values, I need to change some of them with exceptional values (i.e., 5, 6, 8).
I tried to do it as below, but my code couldn't ensure the condition; all values need to appear at least 2 times.
# Counts values
n_id, n_counts = torch.unique(edge_index, return_counts=True)
unique_nodes = n_id[n_counts==1] #tensor([5, 6, 8])
major_nodes = n_id[n_counts>2] #tensor([0, 1, 2, 4, 7])

# Find the index where the major_nodes located
major_s_idx = (edge_index[..., None] == major_nodes).any(-1)[0].nonzero()[:, 0] #tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8])
major_t_idx = (edge_index[..., None] == major_nodes).any(-1)[1].nonzero()[:, 0] #tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9])

result = edge_index.clone()

result[0][major_s_idx[torch.randperm(len(major_s_idx))[:len(unique_nodes)]]] = unique_nodes
result[1][major_t_idx[torch.randperm(len(major_t_idx))[:len(unique_nodes)]]] = unique_nodes

result
# tensor([[0, 0, 6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 8],
#        [5, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 0, 8, 3, 7]]) # 1 is disappeared and 7 remained only one time

Note that the correct result does not need to be the same as the result in the first code block. Just reference.

Your issue arises because you're replacing some of the major nodes with unique nodes randomly, without checking if the major node still appears elsewhere.
Create a list of nodes that appear twice, then for each node find all its occurrences. Finally, randomly select one occurrence to keep and replace the rest with unique nodes:
import torch

edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8],
                       [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 7]])
n_id, n_counts = torch.unique(edge_index, return_counts=True)
unique_nodes = n_id[n_counts==1]
major_nodes = n_id[n_counts>2]
result = edge_index.clone()
for major_node in major_nodes:
    occurrences = torch.nonzero(result == major_node, as_tuple=True)
    keep_idx = torch.randint(len(occurrences[0]), (1,))[0]
    for i in range(len(occurrences[0])):
        if i != keep_idx and len(unique_nodes) > 0:
            result[occurrences[0][i], occurrences[1][i]] = unique_nodes[0]
            unique_nodes = unique_nodes[1:]
print(result)


Greetings! Always thank you for your kind answer. I'll try it soon! :)
